# animate toggle only woking one way

Tags: jquery-animate, toggle

what I am trying to do is on open, menu 1, showing 'Click me to start'. Menu 2, which currently says 'This is menu 2', just for building purposes, is hidden. Then, on first click, menu 1 hides and menu 2 shows, then toggles back on second click. The problem is that once menu 2 is showing and menu 1 is hidden, it won't toggle back.

```
<div id="nav" class="nav">
<div id="whiteboardtext1" class="whiteboardtext1"><p>Click here to start</p></div>
<div id="whiteboardtext2" class="whiteboardtext2"><p>this is menu number 2</p></div>
</div>​

.nav{
    width:700px;
    float:left;

}

.whiteboardtext1{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:110px;
    margin-left:215px;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:whiteboard;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.whiteboardtext2{
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:50px;
    width:650px;
    height:350px;
    font-size:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:whiteboard;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}


​$(document).ready(function(){
$('#whiteboardtext2').hide();
$('#whiteboardtext1').toggle(
function() {
$('#whiteboardtext1').stop().animate({

                        'opasity':'0'

                        }, 'fast');
$('#whiteboardtext2').stop().animate({

                        'opasity':'1'

                        }, 'fast');    
$('#whiteboardtext1').fadeOut();
$('#whiteboardtext2').fadeIn();
},
function() {
$('#whiteboardtext1').stop().animate({

                        'opasity':'1'

                        }, 'fast');
$('#whiteboardtext2').stop().animate({

                        'opasity':'0'

                        }, 'fast');    
$('#whiteboardtext2').fadeOut();
$('#whiteboardtext1').fadeIn();
})
});
```

​

I pretty sure the code is correct, but I just can't get it to work.

If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

Thank in advance

me

Comment: `opasity` is not a valid CSS attribute. Perhaps you wanted to animate `opacity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/M8Tgx/

I changed CSS rules for `.whiteboardtext2` just added `display:none;` by default.

I rewrite your JavaScript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#whiteboardtext1').click(function(){
        $('#whiteboardtext1').fadeOut();
        $('#whiteboardtext2').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#whiteboardtext2').click(function(){
        $('#whiteboardtext1').fadeIn();
        $('#whiteboardtext2').fadeOut();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply. As I thought you may have stuck with using animate I didn't think to mention the the other actions I have within the function

Answer (score 1):

You code is not correct, because you are applying toggle `#whiteboardtext1` element, but when it first call, it hide and the `#whiteboardtext2` get displayed, and you dint apply any event on that, so it is not working as you are expecting. and `opacity` is correct css property.

You can try this to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#whiteboardtext2').hide();
    $('#whiteboardtext1').show();


    $('.nav').on('click', 'div', function() {
        var _this =$(this);
        _this.stop().animate({
                       'opacity':'0'
                    }, 'fast', function(){_this.hide();})

        _this.siblings().stop().animate({
                       'opacity':'1'
                    }, 'fast').show();    
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `toggle` handler is bound to the `#whiteboardtext1` element. Whenever `#whiteboardtext1` is clicked, one text will fade out and the other will fade in, but `#whiteboardtext2` has no click handler, so clicking it has no effect.

Also, `opasity` is not a valid CSS attribute, so animating it has no effect except to delay the subsequent animations. Assuming you wanted to fade the texts in/out, not a delayed sudden change.

Use this:

```
var $text1=$('#whiteboardtext1');
var $text2=$('#whiteboardtext2');

$text1.click(function(){
   $text1.stop().fadeOut("fast");
   $text2.stop().fadeIn("fast");
}

$text2.click(function(){
   $text2.stop().fadeOut("fast");
   $text1.stop().fadeIn("fast");
}
```

Comment: As this is not letting put all of the code in for yourselves to see I will just continue to play around with the code. Yes I realise that opasity is not opacity, and yes opacity is a css3 attribute. Thanks for you your help, i appreciate it